# Not able to use sample() within a for loop: "invalid first arguemnt"

Tags: r

I have a list called indeces. Basically im trying to randomly extract 10 values from indeces at a time, without ever exracting the same value twice, until all values in indeces have been extracted.q is just the length.

```
indeces <- c(1:n)
indeces_used <- c()
for (i in (1:q)){
  p=which(isFALSE(indeces %in% indeces_used))
  candidates = indeces[p]
  ind = sample(candidates,10)
```

It isn't the full loop but right now i have the rest commented out to focus on where the issue is. the last line already gives an error I can't get past: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
invalid first argument
I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Run one bit at a time. `1:5 %in% c()` is `c(FALSE, FALSE, ...)`. `isFALSE(c(FALSE, FALSE, ...))` is `FALSE` (did you mean `== FALSE` so it's vectorized?). `which(FALSE)` is `logical(0)`. Everything goes of the rails from there, because you can't sample from nothing. Also if you're making a loop, you probably want to use `i`, though you likely don't need a loop to do what you're attempting; maybe `split(sample(50), rep(1:5, each = 10))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example based on the variables you have given. As you haven't explicitly declared "indeces" or "q" variables, I have arbitrarily added values for both. Note that if you don't want repeated values within an iteration, you need to add `replace = FALSE` to `sample()`:

```
set.seed(1) # Makes the result in this example reproducible
indeces <- c(1:100)
q <- 10
indeces_used <- c()

for (i in (1:q)){
  p <- which(!(indeces %in% indeces_used))
  candidates <- indeces[p]
  ind <- sample(candidates, 10, replace = FALSE)
  indeces_used <- c(indeces_used, ind)
}

indeces_used
# [1]  68  39   1  34  87  43  14  82  59  51  95  23  61  83   8  81  89  41  93
# [20]  37  54  99  40  44  86  92  52  47  24  32  25  63  57  98  30  56  71  60
# [39]   7  29  50  18   3  74  22  31  97  65   2  80  77  11  45  85  96 100  76
# [58]  17  28  72  26  58  91  53  46  67  94  49  79  66  21  36   4  27  62  12
# [77]  38  16  13  48  84  75  55  42  88  73  20  64   9   6  90   5  15  70  10
# [96]  35  78  33  69  19
```

Given that `length(indeces)` == q * `length(ind)` *and* `replace = FALSE`, this loop will return a vector of every number in indeces. If `length(indeces)` is shorter or longer than 100, these results will differ.